# Angular gridster add custom content

Tags: angularjs, gridster

I have just started using angular-gridster library and I am wondering how I can embed an html page in a widget. I mean, how can I 'point' towards an html resource which loads its data separately etc. etc.
For example, I would like to embed a chart of some sort in a widget with the purpose of creating a dashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually solved it using this answer: [Widgets with different dynamic content (angular-gridster)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051059/widgets-with-different-dynamic-content-angular-gridster)

Slightly more complicated than just using an iframe, yes, but then again you have a better modularity - each widget will have its own directive and all that. Thank you emackey!

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `iframe` element inside of a Gridster widget.  From experience, my recommendation is to detect when the user begins resizing a widget with an embedded iframe, and temporarily set `display: none` on the iframe during the resize, otherwise the browser will have big problems.  Once the resize is done, reveal the iframe again.